# Webpack is mangling my .scss stylesheet classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, webpack

I'm using webpack with npm and react.js, and I have my style.scss stylesheet that controls my styles, etc. I know it gets combined into one big .css file because of 'webpack stuff', but I've always failed to use classes/ids properly with it. I found out why. This, in my style.scss sheet:

```css
/* List items when hovered. */
ul li.hovered{
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    color: #7B8585;
}
```

becomes:

```css
/* List items when hovered. */
ul li.style__hovered___j0Fpj {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  color: #7B8585; }
```

in the combined style.css file. This explains why if I try to manually set a class e.g. `$('#id').toggle("hovered")` it doesn't work, but `$('#id').toggle("style__hovered___j0Fpj")` does. This weird string lasts through refreshes of the page, so I assume it's "safe" to use this in my code, but why does webpack mangle class names like this?? Is there any way to stop it from doing that? Or is this just how it's "meant to be"?

Here's my webpack config:

```js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.jsx', '.scss', '.js', '.json'],
    modulesDirectories: [
      'node_modules',
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules')
    ]
  },
  node: {
    console: true,
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
  ],
  module: {
    noParse: /node_modules\/json-schema\/lib\/validate\.js/,
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
      },
      { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" },
      { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "file-loader" },
      {
        test: /(\.scss|\.css)$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss!sass?sourceMap!toolbox')
      },
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader" }
    ]
  },
  postcss: [autoprefixer]
};
```

Comment: Webpack itself doesn't change your css classes... some of the "webpack stuff" that you have in your config might. We could help you if you post your webpack config.

Comment: Added my webpack.config.js file.

Comment: try changing `ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss!sass?sourceMap!toolbox')` to 
`ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap!toolbox')`

Comment: That removed the funky names, but it also ruined half my styles in the process. At least I know what's causing it.

Comment: Great you can figure the rest out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Css modules in your webpack config is the module that is converting your classnames. It's a really cool module but if you want to use it properly have a better read at the docs https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules. Otherwise remove it

Comment: So, my main problem with the solution in your comments is that it removes the built-in styles for the react-toolbox components which I'd been partially overriding; it leaves them as normal un-styled buttons. Is there any way to get that back? I really just want the styles to not be re-named...

Comment: Ah I didn't realise you were using react-tools components. As it says in their docs they are powered by css-modules so I don't think it will b an easy task removing that. Maybe try overriding the predefined classes as they suggest https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox#user-content-via-classname-property